# Python: display subarray divisible by k , how do I solve with hashtable?

Tags: python, hashtable

I am looking for **Python** solution

For example, For A=[2, -3, 5, 4, 3, -1, 7]. The for k = 3 there is a subarray for example {-3, 5, 4}. For, k=5 there is subarray {-3, 5, 4, 3, -1, 7} etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution. You can try to figure it out yourself.

```
def solve(a, k):
    tbl = {0 : -1}
    sum = 0
    n = len(a)

    for i in xrange(n):
        sum = (sum + a[i]) % k
        if sum in tbl:
               key = tbl[sum]
               result = a[key+1: i+1]
               return result
        tbl[sum] = i
    return []
```

Comment: Thanks, so it mostly makes sense to me

def solve(a, k):
    tbl = {0 : -1}
    sum = 0
    n = len(a)

    for i in range(n):
        sum = (sum + a[i]) % k
        if sum in tbl:
               key = tbl[sum]
               result = [key+1][i+1]
               return result
        tbl[sum] = i
    return []

Comment: So I changed one line here -> result = a[key+1][i+1]  but while running it still trows me error saying that: 
Typeerror: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem' 

Can you help with that @Banach. Thanks.

Comment: a[key+1] will givr you an integer. You cant index integers

Comment: Sorry for the confusion here, but when I run your provided code without any changes I get this error:list indices must be integers, not tuple

Comment: Ahh got it , didn't think of that. Thank you for being patient with me here.